# How to document function that is used only in .call()

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have 2 classes that init some values, same exact way, so I thought I would make a helper function that I will be able to use like so

```
const a = new ObjectA();
const b = new ObjectB();

function f() {
  this.a.b.c = 10;
};

f.call(a);
f.call(b);
```

How would I document that function f so that it is used only for ObjectA and ObjectB?

While writing this I realized I could make a parent object that would have this method and then document it as usual but in my current situation, I feel like it would be a little bit over-engineering.

Comment: Seems like there is a `@this` annotation that can work, however, you might be better off just accepting a parameter, instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple union type, combined with  `@this`, it would look like this `@this {(ObjectA|ObjectB)}`. As @VLAZ says; you might prefer converting to use a param.

```
/** @param {(ObjectA|ObjectB)} foo */
function f(foo) {
  foo.a.b.c = 10;
};
```

[Read more about types in the Closure Compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System)